# how to do Fluterfire configure in E drive

Tags: firebase

How to configure flutter configure in **E drive**.
Pub installs executables into **C:\Users\brayn\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin**, which is not on your path.

My project was in E Drive there is no Appdata in E in Drive.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the `flutterfire` CLI gets installed in the [pub.dev global system cache](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#system-cache). From there:

> When pub gets a remote package, it downloads it into a single system cache directory maintained by pub. On Mac and Linux, this directory defaults to `~/.pub-cache`. On Windows, the directory defaults to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Pub\Cache`, though its exact location may vary depending on the Windows version. You can specify a different location using the `PUB_CACHE` environment variable.

So you can set/change the `PUB_CACHE` environment variable to change the locaton of the pub cache. This will affect all packages that use it, not just the `flutterfire` CLI.